# Is there a setting or settings in QGIS 3 that allows users to modify application tool-tip behavior?

Tags: qgis-3, tooltip

I can't read the longer tool-tip text in QGIS because the tooltop text is longer than the width and it doesn't wrap past 2 lines:
[image]

Is there a setting or configuration change to either widen or heighten the tool-tip?

In QGIS 2.18, the same tool tip doesn't wrap and is wide enough to read:
[image]

High probability that this is a [bug](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues), but I wanted to see if this is resolvable via a setting.

[image]

Comment: Which platform are you using? For Win7, the tooltip works fine and is expanded to contain the whole text.

Comment: I am on Windows 7: `OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601`